# AWS s3 multipart upload fails + memory allocation exhausted + php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, memory-leaks

I am trying to upload the video which is very large about 9GB from my server to s3 input. I have 4GB RAM on server. I am using http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_completeMultipartUpload

also I have set memory_limit to 4GB in script . But still it fails and throw a memory exhausted error - tried to allocate memory bla bla bla .. What i found is 
https://www.eldos.com/forum/read.php?FID=7&TID=6331

Is there any solution to fix this issue? . Below is my sample code.
I am working on laravel 5.1 and using

$client = App::make('aws')->createClient('s3');

```
    try {

        $response = $client->createMultipartUpload(array(
            'Bucket' => $bucket,
            'Key' => $fileName
        ));
        $uploadId = $response['UploadId'];
        // 3. Upload the file in parts.
        $file = fopen(public_path('videos') . '/' . $fileName, 'r');
        $parts = array();
        $partNumber = 1;
        while (!feof($file)) {

            $result = $client->uploadPart(array(
                'Bucket' => $bucket,
                'Key' => $fileName,
                'UploadId' => $uploadId,
                'PartNumber' => $partNumber,
                'Body' => fread($file, 2 * 1024 * 1024),
            ));
            $parts[] = array(
                'PartNumber' => $partNumber++,
                'ETag' => $result['ETag'],
            );
        }
        // 4. Complete multipart upload.
        $result = $client->completeMultipartUpload(array(
            'Bucket' => $bucket,
            'Key' => $fileName,
            'UploadId' => $uploadId,
            'MultipartUpload' => Array(
                'Parts' => $parts,
            ),
        ));

        return $fileName;
    }
    catch (\Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception $e) {
        $result = $client->abortMultipartUpload(array(
            'Bucket' => $bucket,
            'Key' => $fileName,
            'UploadId' => $uploadId
        ));
        throw new Exception($e->getMessage(), NULL, NULL);
    }
Thanks
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it took me a while because I had to learn the following:

- There is a low level API within the AWS SDK for php
- There is a high level API within the AWS SDK for php
- There are different documentations in the wild

What you are looking for, is this:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/s3-multipart-upload.html

Workig code example (from that documentation):

```
use Aws\S3\MultipartUploader;
use Aws\Exception\MultipartUploadException;

$uploader = new MultipartUploader($s3Client, '/path/to/large/file.zip', [
    'bucket' => 'your-bucket',
    'key'    => 'my-file.zip',
]);

try {
    $result = $uploader->upload();
    echo "Upload complete: {$result['ObjectURL']}\n";
} catch (MultipartUploadException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```

The low level API (as in your example) does not work as it creates temporary files of the chosen chunk size as well as eats up the memory (even you destroy the s3_client object).

In my case I did end up in (non catchable) fatal memory exceptions having a full disk and partly uploaded files on the S3 storage (which costs money due to storage use) but are not listed in the normal s3 bucket (see: http://www.deplication.net/2016/06/aws-tip-save-s3-costs-with-abort.html)

This example uses the high-level api which worked fine for me and had a small foodprint.

Links you do not use:

- docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/usingHLmpuPHP.html
- docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LLuploadFilePHP.html